# Variable changing value and unsure of why

Tags: c++

So I'm still fairly new to c++ and programming in general, but I'd like to assume that I have a fairly good grasp of the concept and control flow (possibly lol). I'm currently creating a top down style game that allows the user to interact with the inventory of a chest. The problem that has me extremely confused is that I modify a variable but then it changes to something entirely different after "updating" the console.
[Interactive chest inventory displaying 10 gold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0Tht.png)
[After pressing s to update the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StIB8.png)

The gold amount in the chest is set to 10 in the chestLoot() function, but is then changed to a value of 303, which is the macro for the Healing potion. Why is the chest.gold value being changed to 303 after I set it to 10? Any help on this would be much appreciated. (Don't be too harsh, I'm still new to stack overflow and c++ as well as programming in general)

Here is the code that handles the chest inventory as well as the loot that is generated:

```
void chestLoot(int x)
{

    switch (tutorial.chestIt)
    {
    case 0:
        chest.inventory[x] = WOODEN_SWORD_ID;
        break;

    case 1:
        chest.inventory[x] = GOLD_ID;
        chest.gold = 10;
        break;

    case 2:
        chest.inventory[x] = HEALING_POTION_ID;
        break;

    case 3:
        chest.inventory[x] = LEATHER_HELMET_ID;
        break;
    }
    tutorial.chestIt++;
}
void chestInventory()
{
    bool endLoop = false;
    int x = 0;
    int selection = 0;
    int highlighted = 0;

    while (endLoop == false)
    {
        system("cls");
        std::cout << "Chest:" << std::endl << std::endl;
        if (tutorial.gridChestOpened == false)
            updatePlayer(5);
        for (x = 0; x <= player.level + 3; x++)
        {
            if (tutorial.gridChestOpened == false)
            {
                chestLoot(x);
            }
            switch (chest.inventory[x])
            {
            case WOODEN_SWORD_ID:
                std::cout << x + 1 << ". ";
                if (selection == x)
                {
                    std::cout << "- ";
                    highlighted = selection;
                }
                std::cout << "Wooden Sword";
                break;

            case GOLD_ID:
                std::cout << x + 1 << ". ";
                if (selection == x)
                {
                    std::cout << "- ";
                    highlighted = selection;
                }
                std::cout << chest.gold << " Gold";
                break;

            case HEALING_POTION_ID:
                std::cout << x + 1 << ". ";
                if (selection == x)
                {
                    std::cout << "- ";
                    highlighted = selection;
                }
                std::cout << "Healing Potion";
                break;

            case LEATHER_HELMET_ID:
                std::cout << x + 1 << ". ";
                if (selection == x)
                {
                    std::cout << "- ";
                    highlighted = selection;
                }
                std::cout << "Leather Helmet";
                break;

            case NULL:
                break;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        tutorial.gridChestOpened = true;
        switch (_getch())
        {
        case 'w':
            --selection;
            if (selection < 0)
                selection = 0;
            if (chest.inventory[selection] == NULL)
                ++selection;
            break;

        case 's':
            ++selection;
            if (selection > tutorial.chestIt)
                selection = tutorial.chestIt;
            if (chest.inventory[selection] == NULL)
                --selection;
            break;

        case 'e':
            if (chest.inventory[highlighted] == 0)
            {
                std::cout << "There is nothing there";
                break;
            }
            else if (chest.inventory[highlighted] == GOLD_ID)
            {
                player.gold = player.gold + chest.gold;
                chest.inventory[highlighted] = NULL;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int y = 1; y <= player.level + 9; y++)
                {
                    if (player.inventory[y] == NULL)
                    {
                        player.inventory[y] = chest.inventory[highlighted];
                        chest.inventory[highlighted] = NULL;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case 27:
            endLoop = true;
            drawScreen(NULL);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the global variables that are used in the function:

```
struct Loot
{
    int inventory[2];
    int gold;
}chest, pot;
struct Entity
{
    int position[2] = { 2, 2 };
    int gold = 0;

    int health = 10;
    int level = 1;
    int totalXp = 0;
    int inventory[11];

    int mainHand[2] = {/*location, item*/};
}player/*enemy*/;
struct Grid 
{
    int grid[6][12] = {
       {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
       {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
       {1,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,3,1},
       {1,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
       {1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,1},
       {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,1}
    };
    bool gridChestOpened = false;
    int chestIt = 0;
}tutorial;

// Item ID's
#define WOODEN_SWORD_ID        301
#define GOLD_ID                302
#define HEALING_POTION_ID      303
#define LEATHER_HELMET_ID      304
```

Any tips on improving my code are much appreciated as well :)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StIB8.png): Check Here[Passing a variable from one function to another](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/71511/)

Comment: You asked for tips: This is C++, so don't use `#define` for constants. Use `const` or `constexpr`, depending on the C++ standard that you are coding against.

Comment: Variables which suddenly have changed values are usually an indicator for out-of-bound accesses to something else. It might be a bit tedious to find the actual reason. Debuggung, of course, in combination with [Divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm) is the best hint I can provide. (It's a little bit much and complicated code to debug it by eyes.) ... Using accidentally `=` instead of `==` is another candidate but I couldn't find so far this in the exposed code.

Comment: Nothing really wrong with your code at first sight other than you re using more C than C++. To see what is wrong i nthe flow, we would need an example of `main` to know what data is going in and in which order. At that stage we would essentially do a debugging for you. Are you familiar with debugging?

Comment: It looks like you are writing past the end of the chest.inventory array. Since that array has 2 elements, this would occur it you called chestLoot() with a parameter value greater than 1.

Comment: Check all your accesses to `chest.inventory[xyz]`. Make sure `xyz` is always 0 or 1 (it is 2 elements long).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the member `inventory` of `Loot` is not dimensioned properly. The only valid values for `x` in `chest.invetory[x]` are 0 and 1. Your code is however clearly writing to `chest.inventory[2]`, for example when you call `chestLoot(2)`.

The memory in a struct is laid out sequentially, so `chest.inventory[2] = HEALING_POTION_ID;` will quietly overwrite the next 4 bytes after the `chest.inventory[1]` which is `chest.gold`;

Answer (score 1):

Well, the inventory member of your "loot" struct is an array of ints of length 2.  But you seem to be calling "chestLoot" with a value greater than 1.   This is causing you to go off the end of your array and write to where "gold" should be.